# Is the uncertainity principle explained by disturbances or only by the Fourier picture?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, fourier-transform, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, measurement-problem, observables

Qualitatively, the tradeoff in uncertainty between two non-commuting observables $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$, could be explained by...

1. the Fourier picture where the more one variable is defined (i.e., localized) the more is its Fourier transform undefined (i.e., spread out) in the conjugate domain. Examples include time and frequency (aka. energy), etc.
2. the notion that ([some amount of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_measurement)) wave function collapse is associated with the measurement process. The measurement retrieves the (supposedly pre-existing) value of the measured observable but irrevocably disturbs the conjugate variable (through the stochastic action of unfathomable hidden variables).

Point #1 seems "cleaner" mathematically whereas #2 is arguably more physical and intuitive. At any rate, to what extent are #1 and #2 related and is #2 even a valid intuition for the uncertainty principle?

PS: Cf. a [video by Sean Carroll](https://youtu.be/BJlkkOIFjx4?list=PLrxfgDEc2NxZJcWcrxH3jyjUUrJlnoyzX&t=3755) who claims that #2 is completely unrelated to the uncertainty principle but he doesn't explain why.

Comment: The uncertainty principle applies also to e.g. spins where there's no Fourier transform involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to clarify the distinction between two different things that have been confused since ever for historical reasons:

**The (Parallel) Uncertainty Relations**

The uncertainty relations express the inherent impossibility of preparing a state whose conjoint variance over two observables cannot be reduced arbitrarily. Here, what do we mean by the variance of an observable? We mean that we have infinitely many identical copies of a given state (yes, you cannot clone a state but you can simply prepare identical states) and we perform a measurement of an observable over all those copies. The variance of the observable for the given state is simply the statistical variance of all those observed values. Now, if you want to see how the conjoint variance over two observables behaves for the given state, you perform the measurement of one observable over half of the infinitely many identical copies of the given state and that of another over **another** half of the infinitely many identical copies of the given state. You simply multiply the statistical variances of the observed values of the two observables to get the conjoint variance.

As you can see, as we spell out what is meant by a product such as $\Delta_\psi x\Delta_\psi p$ (where the $\Delta_\psi$ means that the variance is over the state $\psi$), it is incredibly clear that this has nothing to do with how the measurement of one observable might disturb the value of another observable. We are not doing sequential measurements, we are doing parallel measurements on unentangled states.

Now, why would there be a lower limit on such products of variances? It simply has to do with the fact that non--commuting observables cannot be simultaneously diagonalized. They may or may not be Fourier conjugates but to the extent that they cannot be simultaneously diagonalized, their variances cannot simultaneously vanish over a state. This is formalized by the [Robertson-Schrodinger uncertainty relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Robertson%E2%80%93Schr%C3%B6dinger_uncertainty_relations).

**The (Sequential) Uncertainty Principle**

Now, the historical uncertainty principle of Heisenberg referred to how the measurement of one observable would disturb the value of another observable. The first thing to keep in mind here is that this was in the early days of quantum mechanics and it was one of the examples of muddled thinking. The equation that Heisenberg associated with his uncertainty principle actually described the inherent impossibility of preparing a state that is a simultaneous eigenstate of two non--commuting observables, i.e., what we described in the previous section. However, his physical reasoning appealed to what would happen in sequential measurements of two observables over a given state -- not parallel measurements. Now, a sequential version of the uncertainty principle (for which the physical reasoning of "disturbance" is correct) also exists -- but it is not what we usually mean when we talk about the uncertainty principle -- unless otherwise specified, we mean what I called the parallel uncertainty relations.

As for how the sequential uncertainty principle works out, it is quite simple to imagine as to why it would work out. Let's say you have a Gaussian wave-packet of width $d$ that minimizes $\Delta_\psi x\Delta_\psi p$ -- so that $\Delta_\psi p = 1/(\sqrt{2}d)$ in natural units. This means that if you take infinitely many copies of this state and measure the momentum over each of the states, the statistical variance in the observed values will be $1/(\sqrt{2}d)$ in natural units. Now, take another fresh batch of infinitely many identically prepared wave-packets described earlier. You now measure $\hat{x}$ first and then measure $\hat{p}$ on the post-measurement states. When you measure $\hat{x}$ on a state, it will make the post-measurement wavefunction spiked near some value of $x$ and make the $\Delta_{\psi'} x$ very small (the more precise your measurement, the smaller will the variance will be). Notice that $\psi'$ in the subscript says that the variance is over the post-measurement state. Now, since the $\Delta_{\psi'}x$ is small for the state $\psi'$, the $\Delta_{\psi'}p$ will be huge for the state $\psi'$ because of the parallel uncertainty relations. And thus, the act of measurement of $x$ on $\psi$ has increased the $\Delta p$ on the post-measurement state $\psi'$. A precise mathematical expression for the sequential uncertainty relations is more complex than the simple parallel uncertainty relations. They have been derived by Paban and Distler (2012), see https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.4169. They have also been discussed earlier in the literature, for example, Gnanaprasagam and Srinivas (1979), see https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02846858. However, I think the treatment by Paban and Distler is more thorough and modern.

---

Finally, I hope it is clear that the sequential uncertainty principle relies on the parallel uncertainty relations. In particular, the physical argument of the disturbance works only because the parallel uncertainty relations hold for the post-measurement state.

Comment: In the so-called parallel uncertainty relations above, how would you prove it mathematically? (The proof obviously cannot take the standard form of the application of one operator after another, on the same, initially prepared state, in the domain of both, including the flavors of CCRs, because they invariably involve "AB" or "BA".)

Comment: @MahirLokvancic I am not sure what you mean. To the extent that I understand what you mean, I would make three points. 1. The Wiki link to the Robertson-Schrodinger relations that I provided includes a proof of the same. 2. Application of one operator after another on paper does not have anything to do with measuring one operator after another in an experiment. $BA\vert \psi\rangle$ does not, in any sense, stand in correspondence with the process of measuring $A$ and $B$ sequentially on a state $\vert\psi\rangle$. [...]

Comment: [..]  3. The parallel uncertainty relations _are_ the standard uncertainty relations we prove in introductory textbooks.

Comment: "Now, the sequential version of the uncertainty principle (for which the physical reasoning of "disturbance" is correct) is also true".  I think that's not quite correct.  See the work of Ozawa ([on example](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0207121)) in deriving a *generalized measurement-disturbance uncertainty principle*. In particular, the "standard* UP can be violated in certain sequential measurements (shown experimentally later on).

Comment: @march Thanks, I should frame it differently. I meant to say that a version of uncertainty relations emerges also for the sequential measurements -- but yes, these are not the same as the parallel uncertainty relations.

Comment: @march Done. As for Ozawa's work, it's a bit contested as to whether it actually shows what it claims to show, right? Only tangentially related to the current discussion but that's the impression I remember to have gotten from the literature.

Comment: Yeah, I never followed it too closely. There was at least [one criticism](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.111.160405) but at least [one experimental work](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.96.0221370) later on seemed to imply that both Busch et. al.'s approach and Ozawa's approach lead to the same experimental results.  That's about as far as I ever went into it.

Comment: @DvijD.C. I'm really intrigued about your comment that "BA|ψ⟩ does not, in any sense, stand in correspondence with the process of measuring A and B sequentially on a state |ψ⟩". Could you explain, or perhaps provide an example?

Comment: @DvijD.C. Also, your explanation of parallel uncertainty is both compelling and self-contained... which makes any alternative theory (e.g., sequential uncertainty) sound like a red herring. I'm now tempted to completely dismiss any explanation based on "disturbances", and yet the Distler & Paban work still gives it some sort of credence---hence some lingering confusion.

Comment: @Tfovid Regarding your second comment, the usual uncertainty relations (the ones that everyone learns in a course on quantum mechanics) have nothing to do with "disturbances" as I described. The point of Distler and Paban's work is to derive a new set of uncertainty relations that actually apply to successive/sequential measurements and thus capture the phenomenon of "disturbances". In other words, the popular explanation of $A$ is $B$ but it's a wrong explanation of $A$, however, if you pursue what is said in $B$, you can arrive at a new result $C$ for which $B$ is a correct explanation.

Comment: The work of Distler and Paban is about finding $C$. This quote might help clarify what they are doing a bit more: _"In popular
accounts, it is often described as the principle that measuring some observable “disturbs” the system and that this has implications for subsequent observations. As we shall review [...], the Uncertainty Principle does not say anything about successive measurements. In fact, formulating a precise statement about the uncertainties in the result of successive measurements (of non-commuting observables) has received [...] less attention than it deserves."_.

Comment: @youpilat13 It seems that there is a caveat lurking in the statement that "you cannot clone a state but you can simply prepare identical states". How do we know that they are indeed identical? What does "identical" mean if the very properties used to assess similarity/identity don't have well-defined, pre-existing values?

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these explanations are actual explanations of the general quantum mechanical uncertainty principle. The "Fourier explanation" only covers observables that are canonically conjugate (i.e. have the commutation relation $[A,B] = \mathrm{i}\hbar$), and the "collapse explanation" is just nonsense because the uncertainty principle is not a statement about what happens during a single measurement.

The general uncertainty principle (also called the [Robertson-Schrödinger uncertainty relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Robertson%E2%80%93Schr%C3%B6dinger_uncertainty_relations)) is the statement that for two observables $A$ and $B$ we have that
$$ \sigma_A(\psi)\sigma_B(\psi)\geq \frac{1}{2}\lvert\langle [A,B]\rangle_\psi\rvert\tag{1}$$
for any quantum state $\psi$, where $\sigma_A(\psi)$ is the standard deviation of $A$ for $\psi$ and $\langle ...\rangle_\psi$ denotes the expectation value w.r.t. $\psi$. It is an *extremely* straightforward mathematical consequence of quantum mechanical observables being modeled as self-adjoint operators on a Hilbert space, and it only has something to do at all with Fourier transforms because the commutation relation $[A,B]=\mathrm{i}\hbar$ means that $A$ and $B$ can always be modeled as multiplication and differentiation on a function space and the Fourier transform exchanges multiplication and differentiation (this is the [Stone-von Neumann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem)).

Note finally that the uncertainty principle (eq. (1)) is *not* a direct statement about what happens in a single measurement, it is a statement about expectation values and standard deviation and hence a (quantitative!) statement about what happens when you do a lot of measurements on an ensemble of identically prepared states. The only statement about a single measurement it usefully allows is that if its r.h.s. is non-zero, then the state cannot be an eigenstate of both $A$ and $B$ and hence measurement of at least one of them must disturb the state.