Photon and Observer effect
We cannot determine the position and momentum of a particle simultaneously with certainty . The product of uncertainty of them is greater than or equal to reduce planck's constant . The reason for this is said to be that interactions disturb the system . My question is that if there was no relation between energy of a photon and frequency of light or the photon concept didn't at all exist then what would be the uncertainty equation or simply what is the uncertainty equation predicted by classical electrodynamics ? I think there would be because interaction will be still there.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/718659/123208 & links therein.

This link is really helpful
